# WSL has suddenly got no network connectivity

Tags: networking, windows-subsystem-for-linux, network-adapter, wsl2

Whatever connectivity-requiring operation I try to do says network is **unreachable**, even though Windows host accesses internet and local network normally. I'm using a Manjaro distro custom-built from an Arch for WSL2 distro, and that has not caused any problems in two years until now.

At first, I thought it could be caused by a bad update, so I overwrote ext4.vhdx file with the last working back-up, and still got no connection. **The problem is actually distro agnostic, showing up in Ubuntu as well.**

The current `/etc/resolv.conf` is as follows:

```
# This file was automatically generated by WSL. To stop automatic generation of this file, add the following entry to /etc/wsl.conf:
# [network]
# generateResolvConf = false
nameserver 172.25.128.1
```

I tried to set the nameserver to 1.1.1.1 and using `wsl.conf` so it won't be overridden, but that didn't work.

I tried to add nameservers and a default gateway 192.168.15.1 to the vEthernet (WSL) adapter in Windows, but it didn't work as well. My ipconfig is as follows:

```
Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (WSL):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::5058:ecac:1c0c:dab1%71
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.25.128.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::24e4:f9ba:4ded:19ec%4
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.25.236
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Unknown adapter Local Area Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 1:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2804:7f4:c2a6:4111:255d:530e:69e5:9965
   Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : 2804:7f4:c2a6:4111:417c:79cd:521d:ef9f
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::255d:530e:69e5:9965%9
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.15.12
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::f654:20ff:fe67:bd50%9
                                       192.168.15.1

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
```

Windows reboots, `wsl --shutdown` or else didn't work. Other solutions for similar problems don't seem to apply or didn't work. There's no VPN involved. I don't know how else to start troubleshooting this. Any clues?

Comment: Can you access the internet on the Windows host?

Comment: @Randomhero Yes.

Comment: There is some discussion on this issue with potentially further information here: https://www.reddit.com/r/bashonubuntuonwindows/comments/vrm2dm/wsl2_with_no_network_connectivity/

Comment: @FernandoD'Andrea (based on your reddit comment) Does the output of `ip addr` still show `state DOWN` for all adapters in the WSL instance? If WSL says its `eth0:` adapter is disconnected, then you probably need to focus on issues with the host's networking. Maybe hard-disable/re-enable the `vEthernet (WSL)` adapter in windows? Maybe create a second (new) vswitch for your WSL

Comment: @Cpt.Whale It still shows everything as down. Resetting, disabling and tampering with some settings from vEthernet was the first thing tried, always shutting down WSL, before trying to reinstall everything from hyper-v and up. No effect. It has received 401 packets and returned none.

Comment: if you have the patience (and disk space) to experiment, can you install another Linux (ubuntu for example) distribution and see if it will have a connection!?

Comment: @YılmazDurmaz I did this, indeed. No connection. It's a WSL issue, not a linux one.

Comment: then add that detail to your question so others will know you did this check. I keep my WSL disabled since it may cause overheat in this hot summer. But will later check the post if someone found an answer. stay safe ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found. The `%temp%` and the `%localappdata%/Packages` folders were NTFS-compacted. Uncompacting them and performing a `wsl --shutdown` solved the problem.